# oracle report 10g barcode reader not reading

Tags: oracle10g

I install code 128, code39 and Free 3 of 9 Extended but my barcode reader is not reading that codes 
what i tried 
size of barcode 24 to 48 but not succeeded
in code 39 used '*' in start and but unfortunately not succeeded 
i am using normal paper normal printer. is there any need of special printer or paper?
using Ms Word to print after that i have to print in report 6i
chracters are 8,9 to genrate
is there any specific method to generate the barcode. I am just changing the font 
my barcode reader is 1D BLACK COPPER BC-8806
I am generating Alpha numeric

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you did concatenate an asterisk at the beginning and the end of the barcode value, right? E.g. `select '*' || barcode_value ||'*' as bc from ...`. If so, check whether barcode reader is set to read code you use. Some of our barcode scanners came with a book full of different barcodes, so you had to read that certain code from the book in order to "enable" it.

Comment: Sorry to say but not of this i create barcode with these fonts but reader not reading them. I checked reader from other products its working fine maybe i am using barcode font which are not good or what's other thing but which i generate its not reading please help